# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and I worked with it weeks in my laptops, (and I didn't change any setting) but today I got this error when trying to connect to server with windows authentication:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to HOSSEIN.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

I also checked SQL Server Configuration Manager and all the services are running.

Comment: A lot of things can go wrong connecting to a db istance: can you ping it? Do you know the port? Can you telnet and opena socket on that port?
If yes to all question, then we can set up an alias.

Comment: Alias worked, thanks alot :-)

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that SQL Services are running fine. in that case, above error appears when you put wrong SQL Server name or It can be named instance.
If it's default(MSSQLSERVER) instance then try to replace servername with dot (.) while connecting SQL Server by SSMS  or if it's named SQL Instance then cross check your instance name from SQL Server configuration manager.